# How to avoid using setTimeout in jest/enzyme unit test to give react native time to render async functions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

Basically, I have a React Native component which is my Login component. I would like to test multiple state variations.

The first stage of my component is to show a loading component, then, it goes through multiple async functions like:

- NetInfo: In order to see if I can login automatically using network login
- setState: Some state changes, which also have callback functions.
- fetch: To get the information back from the API.

So far, I have both fetch and NetInfo mocked. Coverage shows that some of the functions execute like the callbacks in the setState however the snapchots, for example, show the first original state, which is the loading spinner.

I understand this might be expected, so I tried executing a forceUpdate and updae on the shallow wrapper instance, and there was no change in the snapshot. The only thing that worked for me was to set a timeout of 100ms and then check the wrapper. Also, I need to execute some internal functions manually, because somehow, not all the functions execute, like the callbacks in the setState. This is weird because the coverage shows that the setState execute, but not the callback.

Jest Unit Test:

```
it("should store the confirmation result", (done) => {

        let wrapper = shallow( <LoginComponent
            sms={{
                enabled: true,
                sms_placeholder: 'Phone Number',
                text: 'Enter your phone number',
                buttonSend: {
                    text: 'SEND'
                }
            }}
        />); 
        wrapper.setState({phone: '1234567890'});

        setTimeout(()=>{
            expect(wrapper.update()).toMatchSnapshot();    
            const spySendSms = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), "sendSms");
            const spyError = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), "error");
            wrapper.update().find("[testID='smsButtonSend']").simulate("press");
            expect(spySendSms).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
            expect(spyError).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);                      
            done();         
        }, 100);  });
```

I have been reading about returning a promise to Jest so they are all chained however I only saw that being made with fetch and passing the functions as props to the components, and I have all that functions directly inside the component.

Should I refactor the components that require external functions? Overrride and mock internal functions on every unit test?

It has been really hard to test this complex scenarios.